# Mac OS High Sierra: OS upgrade fails make in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra

I could successfully make before I installed the High sierra Update 10.13.1
My make file has following configs:

```
CC = g++-7
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -fopenmp -Igzstream -Isrc -Isrc/models -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS = -lgomp -lgzstream -lz -lstdc++ -Lgzstream
```

Error thrown is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:65:0,
                 from <REDACTED>,
                 from <REDACTED>:
/usr/include/zlib.h:663:46: error: expected initializer before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_13'
                                              __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_13,__IPHONE_11_0);
                                              ^
```

Taking a closer look at zlib.h at line 663:

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT deflateGetDictionary OF((z_streamp strm,
                                             Bytef *dictionary,
                                             uInt  *dictLength))
                                             __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_13,__IPHONE_11_0);
```

There are multiple lines that throw the same error, and they are all with the __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING
I am not sure how to fix this. I reinstalled xcode command line tools using `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I have hit a similar problem but unfortunately I am not using the system gcc but a custom gcc that comes packaged with the code that I am trying to build. Can you briefly explain the problem why this is happening and why reinstalling and add `$PATH` variable fixed it. May be I can figure out my solution from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bleh.

Reinstall gcc using `brew reinstall gcc`

And also `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`